# odata query in Azure Logic App giving null value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to access an integer value from CRM Entity using Parse JSON in Logic Apps. It is returning a null value instead of an integer value.

```
"territoryinteger": "@{items('For_each')?['_vcm_territoryid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue']}",
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Rashmi, please provide more information about the data model. Otherwise I'm afraid others cannot really provide help. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Runs History (under the Logic App Overview) and drill down to the Get Record or Get List action block, you can see the output of the JSON retrieved and you can visually verify that the query is returning a value.